# Cannot open Tab from another Primary tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, tab, service-console, workspaceapi

I am trying to open a primary tab from another primary tab where the url is a flexi page. It is refreshing the URL of new tab but not opening another tab which is my requirement.
Using workspace api to open tab using URL.

```
subTabHelper: function(Component, strURL) {
    const objWorkSpaceAPI = Component.find("workspace");
    if (objWorkSpaceAPI) {
        const tabUrl = strURL;
        objWorkSpaceAPI.openTab({
            url: tabUrl,
            focus: true
        });
        }
}
```

Comment: use openSubtab instead of opentab

Comment: can you provide sample tabURL? Also the current tab and the new tab you are opening are same?

Comment: URL is a app flexi page with some parameters added.  /lightning/r/flexipageName/parameters